# EthernetInterface instance interrupts program

Tags: c++, embedded, ethernet, mbed

I am testing Ethernet connectivity on a *STM32F746G* discovery board.
However, just having an unconnected instance of *EthernetInterface*, the duration between taking two timestamps sporadically is much longer.

In the example below, 100K times a timestamp is taken and the duration since the previous timestamp is measured.
Without the Ethernet interface, this takes constantly between **1 and 2 us**. Having an Ethernet instance present. It sometimes takes up to **20 us**.

So it looks like my program is getting interrupted. Does someone have an idea, what is actually going on here?

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "EthernetInterface.h"

Serial              pc(SERIAL_TX, SERIAL_RX);   // serial for printf
//EthernetInterface   ethIf;                    // <= INFLUENCES TIMING

int main() 
{
    uint32_t        durationMax    = 0;         // statistics

    Timer timer;    // a timer
    timer.start();  // start it

    uint32_t timeStampLast = timer.read_us();   // sampling timestamp

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        const uint32_t timeStampNowUs   = timer.read_us();
        const uint32_t durationUs       = timeStampNowUs - timeStampLast;

        timeStampLast   = timeStampNowUs;
        durationMax     = std::max(durationMax, durationUs);    
    }
    pc.printf("Duration max: %u us\n", durationMax); // either 3 or 20 ?!
}
```

Comment: It seems that just defining an instance of `EthernetInterface` is enough in order to enable the tx/rx interrupts and begin to receive ethernet packets, which would explain why you are getting interrupts. Also, the "getting interrupted" is an assumption... Could you try your test masking all interrupts except the timer one? So you can test if the interruptions are caused by the ethernet TX/RX module

Comment: You'll have to read the documentation about the driver to see what it does. Is this C or C++? It's quite relevant.

Comment: @Lundin It is C++. I added the tag.

Comment: Then obviously the constructor does some dirty and evil things. No way around reading the manual or the code, I'm afraid.

Comment: @LoPiTaL Thanks for your suggestion. I'll give it a try. Wouldn't 20 us be rather long for an interrupt? For comparison, on an Arduino Due I didn't notice such kind of interruption at all.